# Creating a task that fetch new twitter followers and sends them automated message with gem twitter

Tags: ruby, twitter, rubygems, task

I would like to create a task that collects all my new twitter followers of the day and sends them a welcome message.  I started playing around with the twitter API, using the twitter gem :

https://github.com/sferik/twitter

1) I am reading the documentation, but I cannot seem to find a way to fetch all the new followers of the day. How would you do that ?
2) Is it possible to send them an automated direct message with the gem, once I have retrieved their ids ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the #followers instance method.

> ## followers(user, options = {}) ⇒ Twitter::Cursor

more info in the docs: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/FriendsAndFollowers#followers-instance_method

Comment: Ok so this enables me to fetch a follower, but I still dont see how I can check if the follower has added me on the day I launch the task.